# Extending Product View fails

Tags: magento2, product, blocks, extend

I would like to extend `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` but I get 404

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Custom\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class MyProducts extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
{
    protected $productFactory;

    protected  $_coreRegistry;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $context->getRegistry();

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

}

?>
```

than I created in my module a di.xml which looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" type="Vendor\Custom\Block\MyProducts"/>
</config>
```

than I reference in product view as follows

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Vendor\Custom\Block\Variants" name="variants.tab" template="Vendor_Custom::variants.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Product variations</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructor does not respect the parameters order of the parent class `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View`, which looks like this:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_productHelper = $productHelper;
    $this->urlEncoder = $urlEncoder;
    $this->_jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
    $this->productTypeConfig = $productTypeConfig;
    $this->string = $string;
    $this->_localeFormat = $localeFormat;
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $data
    );
}
```

So to fix your class, your constructor must look like this:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
    ProductFactory $productFactory
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->_coreRegistry = $context->getRegistry();
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $urlEncoder,
        $jsonEncoder,
        $string,
        $productHelper,
        $productTypeConfig,
        $localeFormat,
        $customerSession,
        $productRepository,
        $priceCurrency,
        $data
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your feedback I just corrected the constructor and added inside `var_dump('test'); exit;`  but still getting 404 how do I find out what is causing the problem?

Comment: @fefe try to delete `var/cache`,`var/generation` and `var/page_cache`/ Also check your logs under the `var` folder, 404 in Magento 2 often means an error happened.

Comment: I just checked my logs and I see `main.CRITICAL: exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message product.info.options has a child default`

Comment: seems to be a problem in constructor `[2016-04-18 12:43:46] main.CRITICAL: exception 'Exception' with message 'Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Vendor\Custom\Block\Variants::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context, instance of Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context given, called in /Users/Sites/bsw/var/generation/Vendor/Custom/Block/Variants/Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in /Users/Sites/bsw/app/code/Vendor/Custom/Block/Variants.php on line 20' in …`

Comment: hm this has was an issue wit di compile thanks a lot!!